# Maximization of a function in an interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, constraints

I am writing a computer program where I have $x$ real positive varying in the domain $[\sqrt{U}, U]$. I want the value of $x$ which maximizes:

$$ (1+ \sqrt{U}) - \frac{\sqrt{U}-1}{U-\sqrt{U}} x - \frac{U}{x}  $$

("visually", it seems to be a bit above $2\sqrt{U}$) what is the best way to find it exactly?

Comment: Apply the AM-GM inequality for the last two terms and check if equality is possible.

Comment: The function is 0 at both the end points of the domain, and positive elsewhere in the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ax+\frac bx$ is minimized when $x=\sqrt{b/a}$, and equals $2\sqrt{ ab}$ at that point.

Comment: I cannot see why that answers my question. In my case we have a maximization over an interval, and the form is rather $c +ax+\frac bx$. Surely I am missing your clue: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You have $c-ax-b/x$ which is to be maximized.  That happens when $ax+b/x$ is minimized.  Here $a=(\sqrt{U}-1)/(U-\sqrt{U})$ and $b=U$.

Comment: I see. I get the minimization part. Thank you. Last doubt: how did you know/intuitively see that the solution of the minimization problem would fall in the given interval $[\sqrt{U}, U]$ for the x?

Comment: Actually I didn't.  But you said the function was zero at the endpoints, so I expect a local max or local min between the endpoints.  Then I used calculus to find it.

Comment: Ok. Very nice and useful. Thank you!